# Is there any other way to replace cursor for the following scenario

Tags: oracle, plsql

Table IA

```
Id Status  Details  
1   open    aaa  
2   close   bbb  
3   open    ccc  
4   open    ddd  
5   open    eeee  
6   open    ffff  
7   open    gggg  
8   close   iii  
9   close   hhh  
10  open    jjj  
primary key ID
```

Table snapshot_IA

```
Id  Status  Details  
1   open    aaa  
2   close   bbb  
3   open    ccc  
4   open    ddd  
5   open    eeee  
4   open    ffff  
5   open    sdsd  
4   open    sdsdd
```

1. IA table data changes daily
2. Snapshot table does not have primary key
3. snapshot table should have new rows from table IA
4. snapshot table should get rows from IA table if IA table ID present in snapshot table but status is open in the snapshot table

eg.

```
select T1.id1,T1.status,T1.details from   
IA T1,  
snapshot_IA T2  
where  
T1.id1 = T2.ID1  
and T2.status <> 'close'
```

One way of doing it is using cursor.

Can you suggest any other efficient way than this?

Comment: Have a look at [MERGE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124672/how-to-merge-2-tables-in-oracle)

Comment: I neither see PL/SQL nor a cursor in your question

Comment: I havent uploaded the code. Just wanted to know different ways to do it. Cursor is one of the option.

Comment: Can we add updated_datetime to the IA table?

Comment: Yes... ........

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into IA 
 select T1.id1,T1.status,T1.details from   
IA T1 where not exists (
Select 1 from Snapshot_IA WHERE
T1.id1 = T2.ID1  
and T2.status = 'close')
```